# Non exhaustive error in function

Tags: haskell, brute-force

These are the sections of code relevant to my problem:

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
type Block = [Maybe Int]
type Sudoku = [[Maybe Int]]

blank :: Sudoku -> Pos 
blank sud = let k = ((whichRow sud) -1) in
            let n = ((whereIsNothing (head (drop (k-1) (rows sud)))) -1) in
            (k, n)


whichRow :: Sudoku -> Int
whichRow sud = whichRow' sud 0
  where
    whichRow' (Sudoku [])     i = i
    whichRow' (Sudoku (r:rs)) i = if isNothingPresent r
        then 1
        else whichRow' (Sudoku rs) (i+1)


whereIsNothing :: Block -> Int
whereIsNothing (x:xs) = if x == Nothing then 1 else 1 + whereIsNothing xs


isNothingPresent :: Block -> Bool
isNothingPresent b = not (Nothing `notElem` b)
```

What I want to do here is to, with blank, return a position in the Sudoku that is empty (Meaning its element is Nothing). Since it's customary to start counting at 0 that's what the -1 in the blank function does. The `(Int, Int)` type represents the (row number, element number). Which row has the empty cell, and which of the elements in that row contains the empty cell.

If I runt this with a 'blank' cell in the first 'row', I get the expected result. If, however, the empty cell is located elsewhere than in the first row, i get a non exhaustive error. Pretty sure the whereIsNothing function is the cause of that, there's no basecase. I just can't figure out how to solve it. Any ideas?

edit: When i write a valid solution to a Sudoku, and changes a value in the 2nd row to Nothing, I get the error message:

```
*Main> blank example2
(0,*** Exception: Sudoku.hs:166:1-73: Non-exhaustive patterns in function whereIsNothing
```

So where the function should return the first digit as 1, it returns it as a zero.

Comment: `whereIsNothing`: What happens if the list is empty? Btw, `isNothingPresent` is simply `any (== Nothing)`.

Comment: @Zeta I tried to fashion my blank function in a way that whereIsNothing would be called only if there was a nothing present. I am not certain how i would handle an empty list as an argument for that function.

Comment: @Rewbert you could change `whereIsNothing :: Block -> Maybe Int` and then *pull* it all the way through (you will see that most of your functions are indeed partial - for example how should `blank` return anything when there is no *blank* field left?) *~Luke~: Let the types guide you!*

Comment: Add `whereIsNothing [] = 0`

Comment: also there are some syntax errors in your code - this isn't the one you are running is it?

Comment: @viorior I tried that but when i do that the program keeps running forever, never spitting out the correct answer. Or any answer at all for that matter.

Comment: @Rewbert think, what happens , when `n = -1` in `blank` function

Comment: @Rewbert if you can put up your real/complete code somewhere (in a gist/github repo or something) I can try to find and hunt down the problem - right now I think you would do far better if you did not use `0` for edge cases and use the typesystem instead (the compiler will help you hunt down some of the edge-cases then)

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you're trying to solve Sudoku, you might prefer a certain algebraic simplification: instead of using `[[Maybe Int]]`, you can use `[[[Maybe Bool]]]`, representing the numbers from 1-9 by their possibilities (i.e. `Just 8` becomes `[Just False, Just False, Just False, Just False, Just False, Just False, Just False, Just True, Just False]). So then you've got rows and columns as before, but also *files* based on the new added "depth" to the Sudoku. Your normal Sudoku rules become: there must be exactly one True in every row, exactly one True in every column, exactly one True in every file, and exactly one True at every depth of every "block".

Second, all of what you're doing is solved by library functions. In particular:

```
import Data.Maybe (isNothing, listToMaybe)

allpositions :: [Pos]
allpositions = [(x, y) | x <- [1..9], y <- [1..9]]    

getValue :: Sudoku -> Pos -> Maybe Int
getValue s (x, y) = s !! x !! y

blank :: Sudoku -> Maybe Pos
blank s = listToMaybe $ filter (isNothing . getValue s) allpositions
```

Here `listToMaybe` is a standard library function which is like `head` but it doesn't break when the list is `[]` (so you can catch the case where no blanks are left and you're done with solving the Sudoku!) You may prefer to simply keep a list of blank positions, too.